# How to pass json response back to client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

In my ruby on rails code I want to send back json response to client. Since I am new to ruby on rails I do not know how can I do this. I want to send `error = 1 and success = 0` as json data if data does not save to database and if it successfully saves that it should send `success = 1 and error = 0` Please see my code below

here is my controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html
  def contacts
    error = 0
    success = 1

    @contacts = Contact.new(params[:contact])

    if @contacts.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @result.to_json }
      end
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

here is my javascript code

```
$('.signupbutton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('#updatesBig').serialize();
        var url = 'contacts';
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Look into "respond_to do |format|" as this is how you typically respond to different request formats, html, xml, json, etc.

Comment: @railsdog I added this code to my code `if @contacts.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @result.to_json }
      end
    else
      render "new"
    end`                                                                  But this does not work. It does not even show me any error.

Comment: I think you're going to struggle to get that AJAX request to hit the `contacts` action in the `contacts` controller.
I think it's worth looking at the Rails Guide on routing - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: please see my updates code above

Comment: Currently this code does successfully insert data to database. Now I want o send request back as json to client.

Comment: What do your routes look like (config/routes.rb)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tons of other elegant ways, but this is right:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def contacts
    @contacts = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    if @contacts.save
       render :json => { :error => 0, :success => 1 }
    else
       render :json => { :error => 1, :success => 0 }
    end 
  end

end
```

Add also a route to routes.rb. If you need to use html response you have to include respond_to do |format|.

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust your routes to accept json data

```
match         'yoururl' =>  "contacts#contacts", :format => :json
```

Then it will work