# How to properly pass a JSON in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am new to web development and rails as well.  I created a web app for internal use in php and now am converting it to rails.  Trying to find out what *render* does is difficult.  For example I find definitions like this:

```
render(options = nil, extra_options = {}, &block) protected

Renders the content that will be returned to the browser as the response body.
```

It seems nobody told the author that you do not use a word in its definition.

I was trying to understand render because according to [How to pass json response back to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469578/how-to-pass-json-response-back-to-client) that is a better way of doing the task than the approach I have tried.  But without the other peices I do not know how to implement it.

Could be due to my lack of web experience so if anyone has any links to definitions thats may help please post them.

I get this error:

> Error in GetData: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 2 column 3 of the JSON data

When I print the string in an alert box it appears as one long string so I do not know where "line 2" is.  If I set the limit to 1 I get the same error which really makes "line 2" difficult to find.

Here is an example of the data I get back:

```
[{&quot;DocumentNbr&quot;:&quot;SS9230&quot;,&quot;DocumentRevision&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;DocumentNbr&quot;:&quot;SS8640&quot;,&quot;DocumentRevision&quot;:&quot;17&quot;},{&quot;DocumentNbr&quot;:&quot;SS8618&quot;,&quot;DocumentRevision&quot;:&quot;4&quot;},{&quot;DocumentNbr&quot;:&quot;SS8630&quot;,&quot;DocumentRevision&quot;:&quot;20&quot;},
```

I don't know if the " is supposed to be spelled out as &quot or at least thats how it is displayed in the alert box.  I do not know if thats normal or an error that is causing the JSON.parse to fail.  Any other ways to check data besides the **alert**?

I have a javascript function to call 'GetData' in the view:

```
var wholeNumberData;
wholeNumberData = GetData('wholeNumber', wholeNumber);
```

Which looks like this (stripped down version):

```
function GetData(getType, param) {

    var data;
    var params;

    params = 'wholeNumber=' + param;
    data = SendRequest('wholenumber/index', params);
    return data;
}

function SendRequest(source, params) {

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.open("GET", source + '?' + params, false);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
http.onload = function() {
        //alert('in function');
}
http.send(params);

alert(http.responseText);//Works
return JSON.parse(http.responseText);//FAILS

}
```

The route wholenumber/index points to an index.html.erb cionatining this:

```
<% @list = Wholenumber.where("DocumentNbr LIKE ?", params[:wholeNumber] + "%").limit(10) %>
<%= @list.to_json(:only => [:DocumentNbr, :DocumentRevision]) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of an unusual way to do it, but you could just add `html_safe` to your `to_json` method and it should work how you have it.

```
<%= @list.to_json(:only => [:DocumentNbr, :DocumentRevision]).html_safe %>
```

If you want the control to render JSON, rather than trying to parse JSON from html, you can have the controller action do something like this:

```
def action
  @list = Wholenumber.where("DocumentNbr LIKE ?", params[:wholeNumber] + "%").limit(10)
  render json: @list.to_json(:only => [:DocumentNbr, :DocumentRevision])
end
```

[The Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) have a more thorough walkthrough of Rails rendering

Comment: Thanks for the link, I started reading it before but this time I went about two-thirds of the way down it since you recommended it.  I still cant see how it could work in my case.  If I'm going to create a combobox with the data how does render know where to put it?  Or if I try your method how does the data get into the combobox?  If I'm doing this improperly I would prefer to change my ways now.

Comment: The `render` method can only return one type of result based on the request. If you say `render json`, it is rendering only json. So in this case, going to something like "localhost:3000/controller/action" will be only json, no html. Then you can use your ajax request to load the data from that page into your combobox on a different page. If you want the json and html to be on the same page, you'll have to do something like the first option, using `html_safe`. Then you wouldn't need ajax.